# Overlay Linear Regression Line on Scatter Plot (iPython Notebook)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

```
gh_data = ascii.read('http://dept.astro.lsa.umich.edu/~ericbell/data/GHOSTS/M81/ngc3031-    field15.newphoto_radec')
ra = gh_data['col5'][:]
dec = gh_data['col6'][:]
f606 = gh_data['col3'][:] 
f814 = gh_data['col4'][:]
plot(f6062-f8142,f8142, 'bo', alpha=0.15)  
axis([-1,2.5,27,23]) 
xlabel('F606W-F814W')
ylabel('F814W')
title('Field 14')
```

The data set is imported and organized into different columns, I am trying to overlay a line of best fit, or linear regression over the scatterplot created, but I cannot figure out how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code that is posted just plots a bunch of data points. Where are you computing the regression line?... or is that something you want to compute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rayryeng pointed out, your code just plots the data, but doesn't actually compute any regression results to plot. Here's one way of doing it:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({"y": range(1,11)+np.random.rand(10), 
                     "x": range(1,11)+np.random.rand(10)})
```

Use statsmodels OLS method to fit a regression line, and `params` to extract the coefficient on the single regressor:

```
beta_1 = sm.OLS(data.y, data.x).fit().params
```

Produce a scatterplot and add a regression line:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(data.x, data.y)
ax.plot(range(1,11), [i*beta_1 for i in range(1,11)], label = "best fit")
ax.legend(loc="best")
```

Comment: This doesn't include a constant in the regression. You can just use predict to get the values for new points, or use `fittedvalues` for the prediction at the estimation/training points